# x64dbg injection is not avaliable

Tags: debugging, cheat-engine, x64dbg, anti-debugging

Now, I am new to reverse engineering and I am trying to attach (by x64dbg) to starcraft.exe game process. But after attaching it, this process always closes. Here is my log debug.

> ! Database file: D:\Programs\x64dbg\x64\db\StarCraft.exe.dd64
> [ScyllaHide] Loaded VA for NtUserBlockInput = 0x00007FFFCAAE8450
> [ScyllaHide] Loaded VA for NtUserQueryWindow = 0x00007FFFCAAE1230
> [ScyllaHide] Loaded VA for NtUserGetForegroundWindow = 0x00007FFFCAAE17B0
> [ScyllaHide] Loaded VA for NtUserBuildHwndList = 0x00007FFFCAAE13B0
> [ScyllaHide] Loaded VA for NtUserFindWindowEx = 0x00007FFFCAAE1DB0
> [ScyllaHide] Loaded VA for NtUserGetClassName = 0x00007FFFCAAE1F50
> [ScyllaHide] Loaded VA for NtUserInternalGetWindowText = 0x00007FFFCAAE1C70
> [ScyllaHide] Loaded VA for NtUserGetThreadState = 0x00007FFFCAAE1030
> [ScyllaHide] Hook injection successful, image base 000001A732490000
> Error replacing page: 00007FF79FFE0000[00000000000B6000] (starcraft.exe)
> Sections:
> ".text": 00007FF79ECA1000[0000000000A5F000]
> ".rdata": 00007FF79F700000[00000000002EF000]
> ".data": 00007FF79F9EF000[00000000005E7000]
> ".pdata": 00007FF79FFD6000[0000000000071000]
> ".rodata": 00007FF7A0047000[0000000000001000]
> "_RDATA": 00007FF7A0048000[0000000000002000]
> ".rsrc": 00007FF7A004A000[0000000000038000]
> ".reloc": 00007FF7A0082000[0000000000014000]
> New pages:
> " ".rodata"": 00007FF7A0047000[0000000000001000]
> " "_RDATA"": 00007FF7A0048000[0000000000002000]
> " ".rsrc"": 00007FF7A004A000[0000000000038000]
> " ".reloc"": 00007FF7A0082000[0000000000014000]
> Please report an issue!
> Error replacing page: 00007FF79F9E0000[0000000000600000] (starcraft.exe)
> Sections:
> ".text": 00007FF79ECA1000[0000000000A5F000]
> ".rdata": 00007FF79F700000[00000000002EF000]
> ".data": 00007FF79F9EF000[00000000005E7000]
> ".pdata": 00007FF79FFD6000[0000000000071000]
> ".rodata": 00007FF7A0047000[0000000000001000]
> "_RDATA": 00007FF7A0048000[0000000000002000]
> ".rsrc": 00007FF7A004A000[0000000000038000]
> ".reloc": 00007FF7A0082000[0000000000014000]
> New pages:
> " ".data"": 00007FF79F9EF000[00000000005E7000]
> Please report an issue!
> Error replacing page: 00007FF79ECA0000[0000000000D40000] (starcraft.exe)
> Sections:
> ".text": 00007FF79ECA1000[0000000000A5F000]
> ".rdata": 00007FF79F700000[00000000002EF000]
> ".data": 00007FF79F9EF000[00000000005E7000]
> ".pdata": 00007FF79FFD6000[0000000000071000]
> ".rodata": 00007FF7A0047000[0000000000001000]
> "_RDATA": 00007FF7A0048000[0000000000002000]
> ".rsrc": 00007FF7A004A000[0000000000038000]
> ".reloc": 00007FF7A0082000[0000000000014000]
> New pages:
> "starcraft.exe": 00007FF79ECA0000[0000000000001000]
> " ".text"": 00007FF79ECA1000[0000000000A5F000]
> Please report an issue!
> Process started: 00007FF79ECA0000 C:\Program Files (x86)\StarCraft Remastered\x86_64\StarCraft.exe
> "x86_64\Starcraft.exe" -launch
> argv[0]: x86_64\Starcraft.exe
> argv[1]: -launch
> Attach to a process!
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFCD090000 C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
> Thread 17124 created, Entry: 00007FFF487983A0, Parameter: 0000000000000000
> Thread 17128 created, Entry: 00007FFF48798380, Parameter: 0000000000000000
> Thread 17132 created, Entry: starcraft.00007FF79F67A03C, Parameter: 0000000000000000
> Thread 17136 created, Entry: starcraft.00007FF79F63D240, Parameter: 0000000000000000
> //a lot of threads created
> Thread 16400 created, Entry: starcraft.00007FF79F67A03C, Parameter: 0000000000000000
> Thread 16356 created, Entry: starcraft.00007FF79F67A03C, Parameter: 0000000000000000
> Thread 16648 created, Entry: starcraft.00007FF79F67A03C, Parameter: 0000000000000000
> Thread 17880 created, Entry: ntdll.00007FFFCD0E2B20, Parameter: 000001A7487ED0B0
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFCC960000 C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFCADC0000 C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFC7FB0000 C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll
> Error replacing page: 00007FF79FFE0000[00000000000B6000] (starcraft.exe)
> Sections:
> ".text": 00007FF79ECA1000[0000000000A5F000]
> ".rdata": 00007FF79F700000[00000000002EF000]
> ".data": 00007FF79F9EF000[00000000005E7000]
> ".pdata": 00007FF79FFD6000[0000000000071000]
> ".rodata": 00007FF7A0047000[0000000000001000]
> "_RDATA": 00007FF7A0048000[0000000000002000]
> ".rsrc": 00007FF7A004A000[0000000000038000]
> ".reloc": 00007FF7A0082000[0000000000014000]
> New pages:
> " ".rodata"": 00007FF7A0047000[0000000000001000]
> " "_RDATA"": 00007FF7A0048000[0000000000002000]
> " ".rsrc"": 00007FF7A004A000[0000000000038000]
> " ".reloc"": 00007FF7A0082000[0000000000014000]
> Please report an issue!
> Error replacing page: 00007FF79F9E0000[0000000000600000] (starcraft.exe)
> Sections:
> ".text": 00007FF79ECA1000[0000000000A5F000]
> ".rdata": 00007FF79F700000[00000000002EF000]
> ".data": 00007FF79F9EF000[00000000005E7000]
> ".pdata": 00007FF79FFD6000[0000000000071000]
> ".rodata": 00007FF7A0047000[0000000000001000]
> "_RDATA": 00007FF7A0048000[0000000000002000]
> ".rsrc": 00007FF7A004A000[0000000000038000]
> ".reloc": 00007FF7A0082000[0000000000014000]
> New pages:
> " ".data"": 00007FF79F9EF000[00000000005E7000]
> Please report an issue!
> Error replacing page: 00007FF79ECA0000[0000000000D40000] (starcraft.exe)
> Sections:
> ".text": 00007FF79ECA1000[0000000000A5F000]
> ".rdata": 00007FF79F700000[00000000002EF000]
> ".data": 00007FF79F9EF000[00000000005E7000]
> ".pdata": 00007FF79FFD6000[0000000000071000]
> ".rodata": 00007FF7A0047000[0000000000001000]
> "_RDATA": 00007FF7A0048000[0000000000002000]
> ".rsrc": 00007FF7A004A000[0000000000038000]
> ".reloc": 00007FF7A0082000[0000000000014000]
> New pages:
> "starcraft.exe": 00007FF79ECA0000[0000000000001000]
> " ".text"": 00007FF79ECA1000[0000000000A5F000]
> Please report an issue!
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFCB8E0000 C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFCAAE0000 C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
> //a lot of dll loaded
> DLL loaded: 00007FFF8BB10000 C:\Windows\System32\ncryptsslp.dll
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFC21D0000 C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wbemprox.dll
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFC1110000 C:\Windows\System32\wbemcomn.dll
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFC0C50000 C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFC0500000 C:\Windows\System32\wbem\fastprox.dll
> DLL loaded: 00007FFFB8E60000 C:\Windows\System32\amsi.dll
> Thread 17284 exit
> Thread 17340 exit
> Thread 17344 exit
> Thread 17208 exit
> Thread 17288 exit
> Thread 17292 exit
> Thread 17296 exit
> Thread 17336 exit
> Thread 17276 exit
> Thread 17280 exit
> Thread 17372 exit
> Thread 17376 exit
> Thread 17300 exit
> Thread 17404 exit
> Thread 17308 exit
> Thread 16432 exit
> Thread 16436 exit
> Thread 16440 exit
> Thread 17304 exit
> Thread 17356 exit
> Thread 17364 exit
> Thread 7664 exit
> Thread 16396 exit
> Thread 16416 exit
> Thread 17368 exit
> Thread 16420 exit
> Thread 17360 exit
> Thread 16408 exit
> Process stopped with exit code 0xC0000005 (STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
> Saving the database to D:\Programs\x64dbg\x64\db\StarCraft.exe.dd64 16мс
> Debugging stopped!

The same happens if I try to check what accesses adress in the game. How I can bypass this problem?

I am expecting to debug game process normally and learn how to bypass debug protection. I`ve tryed to use ScillaHide with different settings but nothing changed.